# ASP.NET Core 8 MVC : why is the HttpContextAccessor null?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0

Can somebody please help assist as to why for the code below for the method call to `StringExtensions.Initialize` the parameter `httpContextAccessor` is `HttpContext = null`?

```
serviceCollection.AddHttpContextAccessor();
//serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

var httpContextAccessor = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

StringExtensions.Initialize(httpContextAccessor);
```

I have tried both `serviceCollection.AddHttpContextAccessor()` and `serviceCollection.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>()` yet both yield a null outcome.

As you can see from the order of implementation this should be correct, any advice would be much appreciated.

The above code works for .NET 6, just not in .NET 8.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor? _httpContextAccessor;

    public static void Initialize(IHttpContextAccessor? httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private static string GetAbsoluteUri()
    {
        var request = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request;

        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
        {
            Scheme = request?.Scheme,
            Host = request?.Host.Host,
            Path = request?.Path.ToString(),
            Query = request?.QueryString.ToString()
        };

        return uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
    }
}
```

On further inspection of the serviceCollection, post line `serviceCollection.AddHttpContextAccessor()` I can see that it has been added correctly as per the information below:

Lifetime = Singleton, ServiceType = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor", ImplementationType = "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor"

So why is it `HttpContext = null` in .NET 8, yet in .NET 6 it is `{Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor}`

I have even tried creating a brand new ASP.NET Core Web App project in Visual Studio 2022 with .NET 8.0 (Long Term Support) and added the following code, the result is exactly the same, still null:

**Program.cs**

```
using Test.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddServices();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**ServiceExtentions.cs**

```
namespace Test.Extensions;

public static class ServiceExtentions
{
    public static void AddServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddControllersWithViews();
        serviceCollection.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var httpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    }
}
```

**StringExtensions.cs**

```
namespace Test.Extensions;

public static class StringExtensions
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor? _httpContextAccessor;

    public static void Initialize(IHttpContextAccessor? httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    private static string GetAbsoluteUri()
    {
        var request = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request;

        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
        {
            Scheme = request?.Scheme,
            Host = request?.Host.Host,
            Path = request?.Path.ToString(),
            Query = request?.QueryString.ToString()
        };

        return uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but the `HttpContextAccessor` should be need an actual http request because if I inject it with an http req from the controller I can handle it properly. Could you share all the startup code blocks or the controller?

Comment: I've added the StringExtensions code for context... literally LOL

Comment: :) I was talking about members of the controller or `StartUp` class etc.. Because you should inject required services one of them. BTW, you may think `StringExtensions` as extension but its look like a helper more than extension. If I were you, I use only simple string operatons in the extension and I would avoid using it this way `HttpContext` because it can cause performance issues. But if you have to use it why you don't direct inject in the ctor of the controller?

Comment: .NET 8 has done away with Startup and uses Program instead, this is an actual bug and I have reported it `https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/9040` as even following Microsoft's guidelines re implementation, the code does not work.

Comment: Of course, this could be an issue or bug, but since the http request is sent from the controller, I think that it makes sense to have `null` before it. I mean why don't use like that : https://imgur.com/a/UsUrykQ

Comment: I believe it to be a pipeline behaviour issue, despite following Microsoft's guidelines. I know when using middleware such as `public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RequestDelegate requestDelegate)` the httpContext is available. As you have rightly stated could be done at Controller level, but ultimately depends on the project, how it is structured, what teams have access to what files and therefore what they have access to, thank you for your input.

Comment: I just share the [referance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#properties) about null and possible performance issues. '_Returns null if there is no active HttpContext._', you are welcome 